# How to deal with user added functions in master in VS2022?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to recreate a SQL Server Database project from a live production database in VS2022. I extracted all the different databases from the server as `*.dacpac` and imported them into VS2022, established the references between them and so on.

Now I've got the problem, that in the life database there are additional Stored procedures and functions in the `master`, that were added by the developers and are not part of the default `master`s database that comes with the SQL Server installation.

Thus the references from the databases to these procedures and functions are unresolved, when I reference the System `master` database. So I created a `.dacpac` from the live master database and provided it as `master` reference instead of the system `master` database. But if I do that, I get other errors:

1. I have to manually prefix every use of functions or procedures, that are in the master database as `master.dbo.some_function` instead of simply `some_function`.
2. I get errors and warnings for unresolved references to tables like `sysobjects` and some standard functions and procedures like `SP_EXECUTESQL`, that are in the master, even if I prefix them:

> SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[someProcedure] has an unresolved reference to object master.[dbo].[SP_EXECUTESQL]

Number one is annoying but a problem that I can handle, but number two gives me headaches. How do provide references to a `master` database, that includes both, the user added functions and procedures and the systems default methods and tables? IS there a way to create a `.dacpac` including the System databases?

Comment: When referencing `sp_executesql` it should be as `sys.sp_executesql`. Referencing `master` isn't a good habit for using system procedures, as they are in *all* the databases, and putting `dbo` before it is just *wrong*; it's not on the `dbo` schema.

Comment: Also, honestly, you shouldn't be creating user defined functions in the `master` database either (there are a few exceptions where it's "ok", but I doubt this is one of them). If you want objects that many of your database will use, create a "Utility" database.

Comment: All given ways of referencing sp_executesql throw me an SQL71502 error unresolved reference to object sys.sp_executesql. The only way right now to workaround it, is provide a project reference to master db and call the procedure as master.sys.sp_executesql. I know that custom functions in master a generally a bad idea, but sadly that was not my decision.